# How do I create nested hashes from a flat table in Python?

Tags: python

I am very new to the Python language. I came across one issue, i.e I need to generate nested hashes from a flat table in Python.
Actual output needed:

```
{
    rid:'prkattim',
    'rname':'prashant',
    'proj':[
                {
                    'proid':P0123,
                    'proname':'Colgate Challenge',
                    'allocs':[
                                {
                                    'allocid':'Alloc1',
                                    'allocinfo':'Allocation for month 12',
                                    'price':26
                                },
                                {
                                    'allocid':'Alloc2',
                                    'allocinfo':'Allocation for month 11',
                                    'price':26
                                },
                                {
                                    'allocid':'Alloc3',
                                    'allocinfo':'Allocation for month 10',
                                    'price':24
                                }
                            ]
                },
                {
                    'proid':P0124,
                    'proname':'Ramoji Film city challenge',
                    'allocs':[
                                {
                                    'allocid':'Alloc1',
                                    'allocinfo':'Allocation for month 10',
                                    'price':120
                                }
                            ]
                }   
            ]
}
```

SQL table looks like this

```
id      rid         rname       proid       proname                 allocid         allocinfo           proce
'1'  'prkattim'  'prashant'  'P0123'  'Colget challenge'            'Alloc1'  'Allocation for month 12'  '25'
'2'  'prkattim'  'prashant'  'P0123'  'Colget challenge'            'Alloc2'  'Allocation for month 11'  '26'
'3'  'prkattim'  'prashant'  'P0123'  'Colget challenge'            'Alloc3'  'Allocation for month 10'  '24'
'4'  'prkattim'  'prashant'  'P0124'  'Ramoji Film city challenge'  'Alloc1'  'Allocation for month 10'  '120'
```

[DB flat table view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5nfqT.png)

Please help me with the logic. Thank you in advance.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Can you post some code that you are struggling with?

Answer (score 1):

The output format is called json and is pretty easy to use in python.
I've written short example code to show you how to do this.

```
import json

# create json object and give it attributes "rid", "rname", and "proj" which is an array
data = {}
data["rid"] = "prkattim"
data["rname"] = "prashant"
data["proj"] = [] # in an array you will store other json object

# you can also use variables to as keys and values
for i in range(3):
    proj = {} 
    proj[i] = i*5
    data["proj"].append(proj) # append json object in json array


print json.dumps(data, indent=4,sort_keys=True)
# print and save data
with open('data.txt', 'w') as outfile:  
    json.dump(data, outfile)
```

now you just have to loop through your table and create json object of the data.